# Sendkeys from contextmenustrip

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I would like to send a string to an application from a contextmenustrip. For example, I open Notepad, I open my application, I click the notifyicon from the taskbar, and select an item, I want it to send text (sendkeys.send) to the application that is currently open.

What would be the best way of doing this?

Thanks.

Edit: Simply sending %{TAB} works in all windows versions except Windows 8, and it has to be compaitible.

Comment: It's not a duplicate lol, I want to send it to the underlaying application from the cms, not to a process with the name Notepad...

Comment: A running NotePad application is considered a process. Maybe I'm missing something in the question? could you elaborate ?

Comment: When I have a simple application with no form or whatever, just a notifyicon and an attached contextmenustrip, I want when I click on an item, the contextmenustrip closes, and it sends some test to the underlaying application, whatever that might be. Because when you click on an item in a contextmenustrip, the current window gets out of focus, so sending keys doesn't work.

Comment: sounds like you want to hook onto the process message queue?

Comment: You have to set focus to that Notepad window (`bring it to front`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W8 simply doesn't allow keystrokes to other applications if it is not certified by Microsoft or by Self-Signing.

Comment: Wow, the first Windows 8 feature I like! You could make this answer better by including a link to the documentation that confirms this observation.

Answer (score 0):

The following would find an application (process) by its name. If the application is running it will receive the text. You just need to utilize the code for the ContextMenuStrip. If there is something I might be missing then let me know :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("User32")]
    private static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Process notepad = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault();

        if (notepad != null)
        {
            SetForegroundWindow(notepad.MainWindowHandle);
            SendKeys.SendWait("test");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to nearly all my "it always worked before Windows 8" problems has been to set the process to run as administrator.  In my case I am using SendKeys from perl Win32::GuiTest.  The program runs and sets focus on the right window but refuses to send any keys unless I set it to run as administrator.  This may be because the process I am sending TO is running as administrator, dunno.